# Does an orthogonal decomposition of a vector space exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex vector space equipped with an hermitian form (not necessarily positive definite), $W$ a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ such that it has zero radical (intersection between $W$ and its orthogonal space). Can I express $V$ as a direct sum of $W$ and its orthogonal space? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Let $H$ denote the Hermitian form. Let $w_1,\ldots,w_n,$ be a basis of $W$ with respect to which $H$ is represented by a diagonal matrix with only $1,-1$ and $0$ entries on the diagonal. By assumption on $W$, there are in fact no $0$'s on the diagonal, only $1$'s and $-1$'s. Choose the order of the $w$'s such that$$H(w_i,w_i)=1,\qquad i=1,\ldots,k,$$and$$H(w_i,w_i)=-1,\qquad i=k+1,\ldots,n.$$

Define a projection $P:V\to W$ by$$v\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^kH(v,w_i)w_i-\sum_{i=k+1}^nH(v,w_i)w_i.$$For every $v\in V$ we now have $v=P(v)+(v-P(v))$, where the first summand lies in $W$ and the second is orthogonal to $W$.